# Problems with the grub

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, gnu-screen

Please bear with me, I'm new with this Ubuntu18.4 just installed it a month ago. It was working fine (a little slow but I just asume it id because its a 10 year old laptop). But now when I start it, says  "grub rescue" every 2 out of 4 times. I perform the standard grub rescue with the

> set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)

Thing and it works for a few days just fine but then it starts all over.
Just today I got a new screen. It says at the top

> GNU GRUB 2.0

And I don't know what that means. It takes an awful lot of time jist turning off. It sometimes says that some processes went wrong.

I don't know if I screwed up my laptop. Or what might be going on. I very new to this and I would like to understand what is happening.

Ps: if someone can recommend me a "ubuntu for dummies" guide or book it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like there are hardware issues, perhaps an imminent disk failure. You need to check the HDD's SMART properties. Also, Ubuntu is too much for an old machine. Checkout Xubuntu or Ubuntu-Mate instead.

Comment: @mikewhatever first of all thank you for answering... That being said, it would be great if you can give me some further advise... I was checking on the SMART Data & Self-Tests. It says the disk is ok, 8512 bad sectors. And basically all attributes have type pre-fail or old-age.... So you'd recommend getting a new HDD right?? Any recommendations for a Dell Inspiron... Thanks one more time and forever for your kindness

Comment: Indeed, I do suspect you may need to replace the old HDD. Here is [how to interpret SMART data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) by the way. There is no particular recommendation for a Dell Inspiron. Get an SSD if you can, something like Kingston A400 or any other, they are much faster then HDDs.